Strange behavior of the import package when image and tex file names are the same (except extension)
I find a strange issue of the import package when working on a large tex project.
A minimum running example
I am on Linux Mint 21.3 with texlive 2021.20220204-1.
Here is my folder structure.
/
+- main.tex
|
+- model.png
|
+- dir/
      +- model.tex

The main.tex has content:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\import{dir}{model}

\end{document}

The dir/model.tex has content:
\includegraphics{model}

model.png is just an image file.
When compiling pdflatex main.tex, I met the following error:
! LaTeX Error: File `model' not found.

My initial investigations
In my understanding, includegraphics should search the image file with extensions in some list, e.g, .pdf, .PDF, .png, .PNG, etc. However, model.png is strangely not found, even if I specify \graphicspath{{.}} in main.tex, it still doesn't work.
If I change \import{dir}{model} in main.tex to \input{dir/model}, then the image can be correctly found. (But this is not good.)
If I change \includegraphics{model} in model.tex to \includegraphics{model.png}, then the image can be correctly found. (This is also not good.)
If I move model.png into folder dir, then the image can be correctly found. (This is also not good.)
If I rename dir/model.tex to a different file name, say, dir/model123.tex, then the image can also be correctly found.  (This is also not good.)
This is rather weird. It seems that we'd better not use the same tex file name and image file name when using the import package, however, this just makes people inconvenient.
The complete log
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.3.19)  23 APR 2024 15:34
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen139
\Gin@req@width=\dimen140
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty
Package: import 2020/04/01  v 6.2
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
)
No file main.aux.
\openout1 = `main.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count194
\scratchdimen=\dimen141
\scratchbox=\box51
\nofMPsegments=\count195
\nofMParguments=\count196
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count197
\MPscratchDim=\dimen142
\MPnumerator=\count198
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count199
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
(./dir/model.tex

! LaTeX Error: File `model' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2 \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{model}
                                               
? 
) [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1337 strings out of 479654
 21973 string characters out of 5883416
 305473 words of memory out of 5000000
 19466 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 309 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 55i,5n,62p,200b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/
texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 9020 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


It doesn't seem wise to name your images this way? Are you certain never to compile the .tex file?

I can't reproduce the problem, though. It works OK for me. Which OS? Which TeX distribution?

To the down-voter: why?

The least headache solution would probably be renaming the files to be unique. Because of legacy reasons (not like any developer intentionally want to inconvenience the users), the path search is quite a hack anyway, and the problem might be unfixable.

@cfr Linux Mint 21.3, texlive 2021.20220204-1.

My TeX Live is newer, but I don't get an error with TL 2020 or 2021. I'm also on Linux. Post the complete log.

@cfr please find the complete log above.

@cfr, several reasons to downvote: A) reads like a self-inflicted problem (some later comments more or less confirm), B) posted code seems to be more on a pseudocode level, for dir/model.tex, C) user has been around long enough, i.e. much longer than 2 h, D) don't see, how the Q can be of value to future readers, sep. novices, as its currently written. // I undersand it is and can be a problem, however I'm sure it can be presented more to the point, including better visual structure (i. less visual noise, as logical structure is there).

@MS-SPO Thanks for your suggestions. I met this issue when I was working on a large tex project, and it's my first time to use this import package. After some investigation, I get this minimum running example to show the problem (at least on my PC). So I raise a question here to see whether others can re-produce it. If it's indeed a bug, the solution to this problem can help others a lot.

Thank you. Reduces my list by 1 issue ;-) // For my last issue why don't you introduce 2 or 3 headlines using ### xyz ### ? // BTW I raise it here ... sounds like a good intro to your Q to me.

Great improvement. Removed my downvote. Thank you

@MS-SPO Thank-you. Those suggestions were obviously very helpful.
